# How does the stock market graph updates?

Tags: stock-markets, stock-analysis, nyse

Context: I am not an economist. I am a programmer.

Currently, I am developing a program to simulate the stock market by creating an analogous stock market for a group of people.

One of the main feature of the simulated stock market is the stock market graph/chart. However, I do not know how the real stock market chart updates.

Some research on the internet indicated that the stock market price on the graph updates when there is a transaction. In other words, it updates by the last transaction.

However, this feels weird to me since, if no one is selling or buying, the price on the stock market will stagnate forever. In addition, a few schemers could buy/sell at a high price and bumps the price on the graph. But these scenarios does not appear in real life graphs.

So, how do these stock market graph (like the NYSE) really updates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, this feels weird to me since, if no one is selling or buying, the price on the stock market will stagnate forever.

Why is it weird? If you have no newer valuation, you use the last valuation. There's no "price", there's an "ask" and a "bid". You can use those to determine valuation, but if there are no trades happening it means that the sellers and the buyers are unwilling to agree on what that valuation actually should be.

> In addition, a few schemers could buy/sell at a high price and bumps the price on the graph. But these scenarios does not appear in real life graphs.

Yes they do. The lower trading volume the higher is the volatility risk since there's more chances for an individual trade to make a dent. [Check some of those out](https://www.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/market-movers-high-beta/).

Comment: So does the NYSE and other stock markets update the same way? Just using the last transactions?

Comment: A 'market' generally doesn't have any graphs at all. Indexes do, and their graphs update based on the movements of the underlying participants. There's no graph for NYSE the stock exchange, but there's for "NYSE Composite Index": https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/index/nya

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you mean by "creating an analogous stock market".  Proxies for U.S. markets are indexes and ETFs.  Also, there are individual securities.

Trades are accumulated in a time period on a chart.  If it's a daily chart, the high, low and close are plotted, and sometimes, the open as well.  If it's an intraday chart (1 minute, 5 minute, etc.), all trades made within that time period are combined and the period's high, low, and last are plotted.

Chart updates can be done in several ways.  Here are some possibilities:

1. If there are no trades, the chart remain blank.  If there are solitary trades at a single price, a dot is placed at the chart's respective time and price.  If several trades take place in the time frame, a vertical bar is plotted.  When there are periods with no trades, some will place horizontal dashes in those time gaps.
2. If it's a solid line graph, the gaps will be filled.  For example, if a trade takes place at 1 PM and the next trade is at 3 PM, those datapoints will be connected with a solid line.

You can observe this by charting a stock that is very illiquid at your broker, Yahoo Finance, MarketWatch, etc.

In the final analysis, if you are creating an "analogous stock market for a group of people" then create the tool that you think provides the best information for achieving the group's goals.